# Facebook RTU Access Token

Tags: php, facebook

When my callback URL it's called by facebook, I'm getting a new access token:

```
$this->facebook->getAccessToken();
```

But, the generated access token is invalid. I noticed that the generated token it's my APP_ID|APP_SECRET
How can I generate a valid access token to use on a RTU? (I want to get the user's wall).

Comment: Do you see the permissions dialog? Seems like it's generating an application access token.

Comment: This is a Web Service, don't have a permission dialog.

Comment: If you call getAccessToken() and you're not implementing a login flow first to get a user access token (as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow), it will always return an app access token, with which you can't post to a users wall

Answer (score 0):

if you are receiving RTU from facebook and want to get information from graph api your server side previously should store long-term access_token for user. And this access_token should have correct permissions.

So the flow is next:

1. User loged-in to your app.
2. Your server should store long-term access_token from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#long-via-code)
3. Your server receives RTU from facebook, where you are using previously saved long-term access token for creating session for requests.

It won't work in another way.